# What does the "ON" clause do for this JOIN operation?

Tags: sql

I'm studying the JOIN operation, question 4 ,  on [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation):

```
SELECT team1, team2 , player
FROM game JOIN goal ON (id = matchid)
WHERE player LIKE 'Mario%'
```

What is the purpose of the clause - `ON (id = matchid)`

If we leave it out, what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ON part specifies how the two tables in the join are related (or how they should be connected). If you were to leave out the ON part the query would most likely be invalid (although it might run on some forgiving database systems, in which case you would get the cross product of the two sets, also known as a cartesian product).

Using JOIN without any specifier like INNER, (FULL) OUTER, LEFT, RIGHT or CROSS means you make an INNER JOIN.

Worth noting is that the query processor has to be able to resolve the column names used in the join without any ambiguity, if both tables contain a column`id`or`matchid`the query will fail unless you specify the sources like this:

```
SELECT team1, team2 , player
FROM game JOIN goal ON (game.id = goal.matchid)  -- or maybe it's the other way
WHERE player LIKE 'Mario%'                       -- round, game.matchid = goal.id
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a join condition.

If it's evaluated to `true` then the left row is joined with the right row resulting a combined row that is passed to a result set.

If you omit it, then, depending on a particular sql dialect it might be an error (for example microsoft sql server requires you to use `CROSS JOIN` explicitly) or you might get a cartesian product as a result (that's how mysql behaves).